# ngAnimate with ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-animation

I am having major problems with getting ngAnimate to work with ui-view. The classes never get applied. Please help:

**bower.json**

```
"angular": "1.2.0-rc.2",
"angular-resource": "1.2.0-rc.2",
"angular-ui-router": "0.2.5",
"angular-ui-utils": "~0.0.4",
"angular-animate": "1.2.4",
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="ivy" ng-controller="transitionCtrl">
    <section ui-view></section>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('ivy.transition.controllers.transitionCtrl', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])

.controller('transitionCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {
    console.log('transitioning to ', event, toState);
  });
}]);
```

**SASS**

```
.ng-enter,
.ng-leave {
  @include vendor(transition, all 5s ease-out);
}

.ng-leave {
  @include vendor(transform, translate3d(100%,0,0));
}

.ng-enter {
  @include vendor(transform, translate3d(-100%,0,0));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `index.html` just add `class='my-css-animation'` beside `ui-view`, example:

```
    <section ui-view class='my-css-animation'></section>
```

Also, `angular-animate` should match your `angular` version number.  An angular.js "1.2.4" works with angular-animate.js "1.2.4"

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've updated angular to match and added the class. It still just directly loads the next state, doesn't ever load side by side or add the ng-enter ng-leave classes

Comment: I've had some css animation libraries not work with ui-router, but I do know animations work with ui-router with css from https://github.com/Augus/ngAnimate/

Comment: I don't use css animation libraries. Do you have a working example? I've seen raised bugs with ui-view and ngAnimate so trying to see if anyone has a workaround.

Comment: @MichaelTempest Have you since heard of or know a solution. This is driving me mad.

Comment: @Kiee, unfortunately I haven't had the need since this project, we did get a workaround by sorting the module out ourselves but I no longer work at said company to strip it out for you. sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: @MichaelTempest thanks for the reply, I found a solution to my issue it was to wait on `$viewContentLoaded` then set a franction `$timeout` before adding the data to the variable for some reason ng-enter doesnt fire on load

Answer (score 0):

You need to us the ng-animate attribute:

```
<div ui-view ng-animate="'slideanim'">
```

Note the single quotes inside the double quotes.  Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ST6bZ/) from ui-router faq section.

Comment: Unfortunately that is using an older version of angular than we are, angular animate is no longer bundled

Answer (score 0):

For me it actually ui-view started to animate only after update to angular-ui-router to 0.2.8 and I followed existing example from angular-ui [FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#wiki-how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate) link to [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NsZhDL?p=preview).

My bower config:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2",
    "angular-ui": "~0.4",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.8-bowratic-tedium",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2",
    ....
}, ...
```

that `0.2.8-bowratic-tedium` is a `0.2.8` angular-ui fix for bower as `0.2.8` version does not include release files.